# Jquery hidden form data selector by $(this)

Tags: jquery, forms, selector, this, hidden

i know this is a relatively simple questino but I can't find the answer online.

I am selecting the hidden input of a form as follows:

```
var myVar=$('input#var1').val();
```

The problem is that I have several forms on the page so I want to use $(this) so that I catch the correct form

```
var myVar=$(this).('input#var1').val();
```

But it doesn't work!

Thanks,

Alan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have current form reference in `this` , you can do this -

```
var myVar=$(this).find('input#var1').val();
```

It seems you are having duplicate IDs though -- you can use class instead (*as IDs should be unique*)

If `#var1` were unique, you don't need `this` to reference your input

`var myVar = $('#var1').val();`

Comment: Yeah that works thanks. Why does the use of $(this) require 'find.'?

Comment: `this` is the `form` and your `input` is a children of that form,You can do that other way - `$(this).children('input#var1').val();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the :hidden jQuery selector:

http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

```
var myVar = $(this).find(':hidden').val();
```

Check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/thibraga06/9vXa2/

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var hiddenValue = $('#form').find('input[name=test]');
```